# Sphinx Search Engine using with an access rights table

Tags: database, sphinx

I want to check while searching through sphinx index the read-permission of user who is looking for some documents.

For examle i have an documents table with doc_id, doc_title and doc_is_global. On other side i have an accessprivileges table with an structure like:

user_id, user_group_id, doc_id, doc_category_id

users can grouped in an "user_group" with identifier user_group_id, and documents equivalent into document_categories.

The Access Table could look like:

> user_id, user_group_id, doc_id, doc_category_id
>
> 1 , NULL, 1, NULL
>
> NULL, 12, NULL, 32
>
> 1, NULL, NULL, 31
>
> NULL, 10, 1, NULL

A user should only find documents where is_global flag is set to 1 or he has access by his user_id, or by a group_id he is member of.

In plain MySQL I get the right result by some JOINs Like:

```
    SELECT * from documents d
    LEFT JOIN document_category dc ON dc.doc_id = d.doc_id
    LEFT JOIN access a ON a.user_id = {$user} and a.doc_id = d.doc_id
    LEFT JOIN access a ON a.category_id = dc.category_id and dc.group_id IN ({$groups})
    [...]
```

In Sphinx, I know, I can put multiple attributes to an indexed document but that are not what i want. In my productive envirenment i have also to check which user has given the read access and only if he can do that, the user becomes the access to read.
Made that situation with multiple attributes using sphinx it returns something like:

access_user_id = (1,4,6,2) accessed_by_user = (1,5,3)

so there aren't possibilities to check who gave read permission to who. Next problem is that Sphinx only supports max. 4gb attributes per index.

I need some hint for an idea to build the index to filter out the results the user isn't allowed to see (maybe with multiple indexes?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you can index this with

```
sql_query = 
  SELECT d.doc_id, ...
    GROUP_CONCAT(a.user_id) AS access_user_id,
    GROUP_CONCAT(a.user_group_id) AS access_user_group_id
  FROM documents d
    LEFT JOIN document_category dc ON (dc.doc_id = d.doc_id)
    LEFT JOIN access a ON (a.doc_id = d.doc_id OR a.doc_category_id = dc.category_id)
  GROUP BY doc_id
```

Then can filter on that

```
$cl->setSelect("*, IF(IN({$user},access_user_id),1,0)+IF(IN({$group},access_user_group_id),1,0) AS myint");
$cl->setFilter('myint',array(1,2));
```

> Next problem is that Sphinx only supports max. 4gb attributes per index.

Sphinx only supports 4gb of **string attributes** per index. Are you sure there is such a limit on MVA attributes?

In anycase, if too many attributes - the limit is per index. So shard the index to parts :)

---

As running into issues with max-length in GROUP CONCAT, easiest would probabyl be to use a MVA query.

See the docs for it http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#conf-sql-attr-multi

In there can define a query to fetch the data for the MVA directly, avoids the use of GROUP_CONCAT/GROUP_BY

```
sql_query = SELECT d.doc_id, ... FROM documents d
sql_attr_multi = uint access_user_id from query; SELECT DISTINCT doc_id, a.user_id FROM documents d
    LEFT JOIN document_category dc ON (dc.doc_id = d.doc_id)
    LEFT JOIN access a ON (a.doc_id = d.doc_id OR a.doc_category_id = dc.category_id)
sql_attr_multi = uint access_user_group_id from query; SELECT DISTINCT doc_id, a.user_group_id FROM documents d
    LEFT JOIN document_category dc ON (dc.doc_id = d.doc_id)
    LEFT JOIN access a ON (a.doc_id = d.doc_id OR a.doc_category_id = dc.category_id)
```

(can probably optimise those queries a bit, but at least should show how enough to get started)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, you gave me the right hints. Now I run into the problem with group_concat_max_length. In some cases, it could be that some docs shared to thousands of users. I think it would work with an separate table where all the Data is stored. In Oracle DBMS I would build an pl/sql procedure with dynamic querys and would iterate over the access_user table and so on (package dbms_sql)  to get chunked data and insert it into the temp table. I can do that with php too, but i think its not the best idea. Do you have a 2. hint for me to get that problem working on mysql?

Comment: Edited the answer to include an alterantive to using GROUP_CONCAT.

Comment: >>So shard the index to parts <br/> How it can be done?